# Start shell script after lightdm is being logged in

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication, debian

I have Debian OS, and I want to start shell script after lightdm is being logged in, how can I do that?

I tried to put

> session-setup-script=/path/to/my/script in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

file, but It won't work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5):

Try invoking your script in an `~/.xsession` file.

This file is executed upon X server startup. More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/what-is-xsession-for

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and realised that I had set the option at the wrong point in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, a silly mistake.

The seat defaults are documented before the `[SeatDefaults]` heading and I was placing my setting on the line below the documentation.

so

```
# session-setup-script = Script to run when starting a user session (runs as root)
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/bla
```

Looking further down the file I found the heading `[SeatDefaults]` and below that the setting.

```
#session-setup-script=
```

Un-commenting that line and setting the script worked as expected.